# How to set custom header on form-data item?

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data, form-data

I am sending a multipart data from a nodeJS route as a response.
I used `form-data` library to accomplish, my requirement is to send additional header information for all binary data.

I tried the following

```
 router.get('/getdata', async (req, res, next) => {
    var form = new FormData();
    var encodedImage2 = fs.readFileSync('./public/image2.png');

    var CRLF = '\r\n';
    var options = {
        header: CRLF + '--' + form.getBoundary() + CRLF + 'X-Custom-Header: 123' + CRLF + CRLF
    };
    form.append('image2.png', encodedImage2, options);

    res.set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + form.getBoundary());
    form.pipe(res);
 });
```

in the output I get only the header

```
X-Custom-Header: 123
```

without the `option` object I can get

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image2.png"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

I need an output headers something like

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image2.png"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
X-custom-Header: 123
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution myself, and its very simple.
Its posible to set custom headers in the options object header property

```
router.get('/getdata', async (req, res, next) => {
    var form = new FormData();
    var encodedImage2 = fs.readFileSync('./public/image2.png');
    var options = {
        header: {
           'X-Custom-Header': 123
       }
    };
    form.append('image2.png', encodedImage2, options);

    res.set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + form.getBoundary());
    form.pipe(res); 
});
```

Comment: Isn't this just the same than my answer below?

Comment: @MarcosLuis in your answer you are adding the header to the response, I need to add header to individual form item. we can set header option in `FormData` individual item

Answer (score 0):

Just set your headers in `express`'s `res` object like you do with the `Content-Type`:

```
router.get('/getdata', async (req, res, next) => {
    var form = new FormData();
    form.append('image2.png', fs.readFileSync('./public/image2.png'));

    res.set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + form.getBoundary());
    res.set('X-Custom-Header', '123'); // Set header here
    form.pipe(res);
 });
```

Comment: your solution is adding the header to the response. I need to add custom header to individual form binary item.

Comment: You can't really do that, there is one response so there is one `headers`. Do you mean adding a property to the response? Are you sending multiple files?

Comment: Then you should add multiple headers and map them to the files